# how to pass value via url in php?

Tags: php

```
onClick=window.open('adddec.php?category=<?php echo $invoice_no ?>'.'&tax=<?php echo $_REQUEST["tax"]; ?>',"Ratting","width=350,height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0,");>Add Item</a>
```

please tell me where is the error.

Error:

```
SyntaxError: missing name after . operator
```

Comment: Can you give more context? You can't just have opening PHP tags in the middle of a normal string...

Comment: onClick=window.open('adddec.php?category=<?php echo $invoice_no ?>'.'&tax=<?php echo $_REQUEST["tax"]; ?>',"Ratting","width=350,height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0,");>Add Item</a>

Comment: add semicolon after your string like `<?php echo $invoice_no; ?>`

Comment: This doesn't look at all like valid PHP.  If this whole string is client-side then the `.` operator is out of place.  If this whole string is server-side then the `<?php ?>` tags are out of place.

Comment: @lakmal can you give more context again? Is that inside a PHP file, is that printed inside PHP tags?

Answer (score 2):

`.` is to concatenate a string in PHP. But the line was outside PHP blocks so JavaScript.
The `.` in JavaScript is for objects.

So it should be something like:

```
onClick=window.open('adddec.php?category=<?php echo $invoice_no ?>&tax=<?php echo $_REQUEST["tax"]; ?>',"Ratting","width=350,height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0,");>Add Item</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Build the url togheter and then use it in your output in the javascript function

```
<?php
$url = "adddec.php?category='".$invoice_no."'&tax='".$_REQUEST["tax"]."'";
echo "<a href='#' onclick=\"window.open('".$url."','Rating', 'width=350, height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0'); return false;\">Add Item</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect the `.` operator to do in JavaScript code?  If you want to concatenate the strings, that would be done with the `+` operator:

```
onClick=window.open(
    'adddec.php?category=<?php echo $invoice_no ?>' + '&tax=<?php echo $_REQUEST["tax"]; ?>',
    "Ratting",
    "width=350,height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0,");>Add Item</a>
```

Hint: When you see the error on your *browser console* then it's a client-side error, not server-side.  Which means it has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
'adddec.php?category=' . $invoice_no . '&tax=' . $_REQUEST["tax"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses `+` for string concatenation, not `.`:

```
onClick=window.open('adddec.php?category=<?php echo $invoice_no ?>'+'&tax=<?php echo $_REQUEST["tax"]; ?>',"Ratting","width=350,height=150,left=20,top=20,status=0,");>Add Item</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I can not test here, but I believe that lack of concatenation points. Try it, or something....
'adddec.php?category='.'.'&tax='..'